# Gateway and aggregator - CorrelationStrategy error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I have to access an external service using spring integration. The process is (1) I had to pass an id to get basic information (2) using basic info from step 1, I need to access to more services and merge the information into a singlr object.
integration-graph:
input: Channel1 outputs to : Channel1Out
I have recipient list router that puts message to the 2 channels Channel2 and Channel3.

Channel2 and Channel3's output channels use a xml xpath-transformer
 and output to Channel 4

```
<int:aggregator id="aggregatorChannel"      
                    correlation-strategy-expression="headers['jms_messageId']"  
                    release-strategy-expression="size() == 2" method="mergeVO"
                    input-channel="channel4" output-channel="dest-channel">
            <bean class="n.b.lbr.eai.vo.PojoAggregator"></bean>
    </int:aggregator>
```

This is giving error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null correlation not allowed.  Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing?
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:385) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
```

I did see some posts on this topic, but I do not understand how to solve the below error

```
{
    "timestamp": 1533137160301,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.IllegalStateException",
    "message": "Null correlation not allowed.  Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing?",
    "path": "/w/b/search/11223"
}
```

please suggest, if this is a design issue or how to solve this problem

**EDIT1:**
Is the below valid scatter gather?

```
<bean id="messageStore" class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore"/>
    <int:scatter-gather id="scatterGather2" input-channel="drBInputChannel" gather-channel="gatherChannel" gather-timeout="5000">
        <int:scatterer id="myScatterer" apply-sequence="true">
            <int:recipient channel="bserviceInputChannel"/>
            <int:recipient channel="aserviceInputChannel"/>
        </int:scatterer>
        <int:gatherer id="myGatherer" 
                **??**
                message-store="messageStore"
                correlation-strategy=**??**
                release-strategy-expression="size() == 2"
                >
        <bean class="nd.wbr.eai.vo.PojoAggregator"></bean>
        </int:gatherer>
    </int:scatter-gather>
```

I need help to convert to xml and use in the above

```
@Bean
public MessageHandler gatherer() {
    return new AggregatingMessageHandler(
            ***new ExpressionEvaluatingMessageGroupProcessor("^[payload gt 5] ?:-1D"),***
            new SimpleMessageStore(),
            ***new HeaderAttributeCorrelationStrategy(
                   IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CORRELATION_ID),***
            new ExpressionEvaluatingReleaseStrategy("size() == 2"));
}
```

Comment: It means one of the messages doesn't have that `jms_messageId` header. DEBUG logging will show all the messages flowing and you can examine the headers.

Answer (score 0):

The "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null correlation not allowed.  Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing?" exception means that your `correlation-strategy-expression="headers['jms_messageId']"` doesn't produce anything meaningful. To be precise there is just no `jms_messageId` header in the message.

Not sure why you did such a choice for the correlation key, but there is definitely not going to be such a headers when you perform HTTP request. You may emulate it though, but it might be better to choose some other correlation strategy.

On the other hand, looking to your original task description, I would say that you need to take a look into the [Scatter-Gather](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#scatter-gather) pattern and stop to worry about correlation key altogether!

Comment: I did see scatter gather.  "to rely just on the default correlationStrategy for the recipient-list-router and the aggregator, you should specify apply-sequence="true". - So included that now.but how to convert @Bean
public MessageHandler gatherer() {
 ...} to xml. especially new ExpressionEvaluatingMessageGroupProcessor("^[payload gt 5] ?: -1D"),
Please see EDIT1

Comment: That goes to the `expression` of the `<gatherer>`.

Comment: Did you get your problem with the `jms_mesaageId`? That’s actually was an original question and we should pursue this one here. If the rest in my answer is not clear for you, then we should move it into a new SO thread.

Comment: Originally I did develop using JMS inbound and outbound adapters, jms_messageId was valid at that time. Now I wanted to remove JMS queues and use gateway, which is when messageId no longer exists. Hence asking for any design suggestion. Note: I removed correlation-strategy-expression from aggregator and it works, but not sure of any incorrect results, if dozens of requests are made in parallel.